# Unable to convert a json array into java list

Tags: java, arrays, json

I have the following Json string:

```
String jsonString = "[
  {
    "nameOnCard": "Test T",
    "active": true,
    "declineReason": null
  },
  {
    "nameOnCard": "TestT",
    "active": false,
    "declineReason": "payment_stolen"
  }
]";
```

The string is contained in an object called `ApiResponse` in a field called `data`. E.g.

```
APIResponse apiResponse = APIResponse.builder()
                .data(jsonString)
                .build();
```

I am trying to map the contents of the string into a list of `PaymentObject`.
The payment object looks like this:

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class PaymentObject {

    private String declineReason;
    private String nameOnCard;
    private String active; 
}
```

I am using the following to convert the String into a `List<PaymentObject>` by the following:

`List<PaymentObject> paymentObjectDTOs = mapper.convertValue(apiResponse.getData(), new TypeReference<>() {});`

where `mapper` is `ObjectMapper` from Jackson 2.13.2.2.

But I am getting the following error:

```
Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.ArrayList<com.abc.PaymentObject>` from String value (token `JsonToken.VALUE_STRING`)
 at [Source: UNKNOWN; byte offset: #UNKNOWN]
```

I can't see what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the referenced type. This will work:

```
List<PaymentObject> paymentObjectDTOs =mapper.readValue(apiResponse.getData(), new TypeReference<List<PaymentObject>>(){});
```

But make sure you've all the getters and setters methods on the PaymentObject class, as well as the default constructor.

Comment: The generic type parameters can be inferred from the type on the left-hand side, but your answer works because you're using the correct method, `readValue`.